# CSS Property included correctly but still not working

Tags: css, background-image

I have added css property correctly in style.css and all other things are also right but still its not getting on screen

css:

```
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(background.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

html:

```
<body>
    <div class="header" id="header">

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Did you add a `<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">` or just `<style></style>` in the html file? If you didn't that might be the case

Comment: Make sure there’s actually a `css` folder in the same directory as your HTML file, and that it truly contains the `style.css`. Also, inspect the `#header.header` to see if there’s other rules (with higher specificity) styles overriding your rule.

Comment: yes,,checked all things ...now i am only using id but still no op

Comment: Try to put `?=v1` at your href like `href="styles.css?=v1"`. This will force the browser to reload the script avoiding cache.

Answer (score 0):

You might have linked to the Styles.css file incorrectly, try using this CSS code in the head tag using the  tag and see the result or make sure your code referencing the styles document is something along the lines of

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
```

Let me know if it works/ if you have another problem

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
i have linked it properly.

Comment: Other properties are working fine just have problem with this one

Answer (score 0):

You need to reset the default browser properties, after that it will work. Also you can write like this or can use normalise.css or reset.css libraries for the same.

It works fine without resetting the default value if fixed value of height and width is given but doesn't work with vh

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: url(background.png);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="header" id="header">

    </div>
</body>
```